# How do I view all ArrayList entries and remove specific ones?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have a customer, customers and main class. I have an ArrayList in the customers class to store each customer. I think I have successfully added customers. How do I display all the customers in the ArrayList and how would I remove a specific one? I am trying to create a method in the customer class and call on it in the main.

**Customer Class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class customer {


    //create variables
    private int Id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    public customer() {

    }


    //setters and getters
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) throws InputValidationException {
        if (firstName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) throws InputValidationException {
        if (lastName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }



    //constructor
    public customer(int Id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
       }

    //get user input
    public void customerInfo() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        {
            while (true) {
                //ask user for input and get input
                System.out.println("Enter id (press 'q' to quit): ");
                String temp = input.nextLine();
                if (temp.equals("q")) break;

                int id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

                System.out.println("Enter first name:");
                String firstName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter last name:");
                String lastName = input.nextLine();


                //add customer
                customers.add(new customer(id, firstName, lastName));

            }

        }
    }
    public  void displayCustomers() {
        System.out.println("Customer List : ");

        }
    }
```

**Customers Class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//creates an array of the customers

public final class customers {
    public static ArrayList<customer> customers;

        public customers() {
            customers = new ArrayList<customer>();
        }


    public static void add(customer customer) {
    }

}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        customer customerInfoObject = new customer();
        customerInfoObject.customerInfo();

        customer displayCustomersObject = new customer();
        displayCustomersObject.displayCustomers();

    }
}
```

Comment: You should implement `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `customer`.

Comment: How do I do this? What code in which class?

Answer (score 1):

To print the information of all customers of the list, use a loop.
There are different ways for the user to delete a customer. You could receive an integer from the user and delete the customer at the given index. You could also receive the customer-name and compare it in a loop to the names of the customers and delete the one with the received name.

Also, dont use empty brackets. Just put an `!` in front of the if-condition to invert it

Comment: That will work, but it is not the OO way to do this operations. Implement `toString()` and do `System.out.println(list)` and you are done w/o looping, etc. To remove, do not loop. `List` has a `remove(Object x)` method. For that you must implement `equals()`.

Comment: I think that printing a list looks not very user-friendly, but probably thats just my opinion. The problem with remove(Object x) is, that he does not use a list of primitive datatypes. So you have to create a new object that has the same values as the one to be removed and in some cases it is possible that you dont have all the necessary data to do that.

Comment: @PeterMmm that sounds like what I want to do, how do i implement this?